# Why are tables not created during migration?

Tags: python, django

Authorization tables were created normally. When I try to create and apply a migration, it says that everything was successful. But there are no new tables in the database

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'start_page'
]
```

file 0001_initial.py in folder migrations

```
# Generated by Django 4.2.5 on 2023-10-15 14:17

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('age', models.IntegerField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

in console

(.venv) C:\django-on-docker\app>python manage.py makemigrations start_page
Migrations for 'start_page':
start_page\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Person

(.venv) C:\django-on-docker\app>python manage.py migrate start_page
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: start_page
Running migrations:
Applying start_page.0001_initial... OK

but there is no new table in the database, there are only tables created for authorization

And there is no new entry in the table django_migrations

If I create a new user in the admin panel, he appears in auth_user And then I can log in with a new account. This means the database is working and there is a connection with it.

Comment: Have you tried to re-create bd and run migrations?